# post test execution callbacks available?

Tags: origen-sdk

I am looking to apply a callback post test execution that will check for an alarm flag.  I don't see any listed [here](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/callbacks/) so I then checked the test interface and only see what looks like a flow level callback:

```rb
# This will be called at the end of every flow or sub-flow (at the end of every
# Flow.create block).
# Any options passed to Flow.create will be passed in here.
# The options will contain top_level: true, whenever this is called at the end of a
# top-level flow file.
def shutdown(options = {})
end
```

We need the ability to check the alarm flags after every test but still apply a common group ID to a list of tests like this:

```rb
group "func tests", id: :func do
  [:minvdd, :maxvdd].each do |cond|
    func :bin1_1200, ip: :cpu, testmode: :speed, cond: cond
  end
end
```

Here is an example of the V93K alarm flow flag:

[image]

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common when writing interfaces to funnel all test generation methods through a common single method to add them to the flow:

```rb
def func(name, options = {})
  t = test_suites.add(name)
  t.test_method = test_methods.origen.functional_test(options)
  add_to_flow(t, options)
end

def para(name, options = {})
  t = test_suites.add(name)
  t.test_method = test_methods.origen.parametric_test(options)
  add_to_flow(t, options)
end

def add_to_flow(test_obj, options = {})
  # Here you can do anything you want before adding each test to the flow
  flow.test(test_obj, options)
  # Here you can do anything you want after adding each test to the flow
end
```

So while there is no per-test callback, you can generally achieve whatever you wanted to do with one via the above interface architecture.

EDIT:

With reference to the alarm flag flow structure you want to create, you would code it like this:

```rb
func :some_func_test, id: :sft1

if_failed :sft1 do
  bin 10, if_flag: "Alarm"
  bin 11, unless_flag: "Alarm"
end
```

Or, if you prefer, this is equivalent:

```rb
func :some_func_test, id: :sft1

bin 10, if_flag: "Alarm", if_failed: :sft1
bin 11, unless_flag: "Alarm", if_failed: :sft1
```

At the time of writing, that will generate something logically correct but with a sub-optimal branch structure.
In the next release that will be fixed, see [the test case that has been added here](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/2b76caa8b6a17ead3a1c4d328ad4ff4ff5d0e01b/program/components/_prb1_main.rb#L211) and the [output it generates here](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/2b76caa8b6a17ead3a1c4d328ad4ff4ff5d0e01b/approved/v93k/prb1.tf#L1932).

You can call all of the flow control methods from the interface the same way you can from within the flow, so you can inject such conditions in the `add_to_flow` method if you want.

Note also that in the test case both `if_flag` and `if_enable` are used. `if_enable` should generally be used if the flag is something that would be set at the start of the flow (e.g. by the operator) and would not change. `if_flag` should be used if it is a flag that is subject to modification by the flow at runtime.

Comment: so what is the API to check a flow flag called 'Alarm' inside the test interface?  Are all of the Flow methods (http://origen-sdk.org/testers/api/OrigenTesters/Flow.html) available within the test interface?

Comment: What do you mean by "a flow flag called 'Alarm'" ?

Comment: I added in the Alarm flag picture from the V93K flow tool.

Comment: thanks Ginty, that cleared up the confusion quite nicely.

Comment: After closer review, it seems that Origen is making all flags uppercase (origin_testers/lib/origin_testers/smartest_based_tester/base/flow.rb).  Why is that?